# I have an OutOfMemory error when reading images

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, out-of-memory, javax.imageio

All right, so I am reading images in a subdirectory in the .jar file called 'images', and of course I have to access them via a stream because it's in a .jar. This is what reads the images:

```
    private Image wPawn = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/WhitePawn.png")),
        bPawn = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/BlackPawn.png")),
        wRook = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/WhiteRook.png")),
        bRook = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/BlackRook.png")),
        wKnight = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/WhiteKnight.png")),
        bKnight = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/BlackKnight.png")),
        wBishop = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/WhiteBishop.png")),
        bBishop = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/BlackBishop.png")),
        wQueen = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/WhiteQueen.png")),
        bQueen = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/BlackQueen.png")),
        wKing = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/WhiteKing.png")),
        bKing = getImage(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/BlackKing.png"));
private Image getImage(InputStream stream){
    Image i;
    try{
        i = ImageIO.read(stream);
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        i = null;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This code works, but the chess game that runs is simply terribly behind with my mouse inputs. Before, I had a small separate class that did this same job, but it did not result in an OutOfMemoryError.

The error comes from the line with `i = ImageIO.read(stream);`
and it is called from the image declarations. Can anyone help be figure out the best way to combtat the error?

Comment: @Cameron The problem is not the file size, as I mentioned before with the pieces working with the separate class. My PNGs are 150x150 2-color PNGs with transparent backgrounds.

Comment: It's always hard to diagnose OutOfMemoryErrors, so you need all the information you can get. It's important to rule out the size of the images early on, so that's why I asked.

Comment: Unless your PNG files for the pieces are unreasonably large (decoded image dimensions, not file size), it's unlikely that the problem is shown in the code you have posted. It's more like that something else eats all the memory before you get to the icon loading, or perhaps that you load the icons multiple times. Remember that the `OutOfMemoryError` will just tell you what the JVM was doing at the moment it ran out of memory. Not necessarily the same as what consumed the memory in the first place.

Comment: Q: *Can anyone help be figure out the best way to combat the error?* A: Use a memory profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Optimize/resise/compress your images. There's no way twelve PNGs representing simple chess pieces at sizes to be used in a game should take up enough space to run you out of memory, even at 32M or 64M heap sizes.

Comment: The problem is not the file size, as I mentioned before with the pieces working with the separate class. My PNGs are 150x150 2-color PNGs with transparent backgrounds.

Comment: It could be entirely unrelated to the images, but my next guess would be that you're loading the images repeatedly instead of loading them once and caching them for future use. Otherwise, you'll want to do some memory profiling to find out what objects are taking up all the space.

Comment: This is a bit late of a response, but I only load the pngs once, and save them as Images (actually BufferedImages, as that's what ImageIO gives you, but I only read them as Images). These Images are constantly called upon, but they are only actually read once.

Comment: In addition, as I'm not familiar with how memory is managed for each separate class, would the separate class have a separate allocated memory stockpile that the ChessPiece class never touches, or is the memory for each class all part of the same pile?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you must do a lot of IO (i.e, reading a whole bunch of images), you can always increase the total heap consumed by your java application.

an example to do that would look like this:

> java -Xms128m -Xmx256m YourClassNameHere

Throwing more resources at a problem is never a solution unless you know that there is no way around it. I would use this solution as a last resort after you have optimized your solution and have ensured that no memory is being wasted and the application really needs to use extra memory.

Comment: The memory allocated shouldn't be the issue, because the application worked just fine with no lag when I used a separate class to get the images via ImageIO.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to diagnose OOMs is to use a profiler. [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) is pretty good and I believe it has a free trial period.

Also, remember that OOMs are often misleading. Just because the OOM is thrown at one particular line doesn't actually mean that's the line that uses a lot of memory; it's just the line that used the *last* bit of available memory. For example:

```
byte[] unused = new byte[availableMemory - 1];
byte[] reallyImportant = new byte[10]; // throws OutOfMemoryError
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image.read()` caches the image data in memory/disk.

Have answered a similar question. [Please Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8222300/760656)