# Reading images using ImageIO.read(file); causes java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, javax.imageio

I am using a ImageIO API to write a PNG file. This code is called in a loop and causes an OutOfMemory error. Is there anyway the following code can be fixed to avoid the OutOfMemory error? Or is the only option to increase the JVM heap size?

```
File file = new File(resultMap.get("outputFile").toString());

//ImageIO to convert jpg to png
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
file = new File(resultMap.get("outputFile").toString() + ".png");
ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
```

Java heap size is 1024M.

Comment: What are your current memory settings on server and what is the size/number of images you are processing?

Comment: How large is your heap setting (-Xmx)?  How big of images are you reading in?  A BufferedImage is a completely uncompressed image so even a small 2MB image can occupy 45MB in memory when fully uncompressed.  Doing this in a loop and I could easily see how you blow out your memory.

Comment: @chubbard The images are 1MB or less. What are the alternatives to BufferedImage?

Comment: What is the format of your input file? *If* they are PNG files themeselves, then you're doing lots of unnecessary work. (Sorry if this seems obvious, but I've seen this mistake done a lot).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I had to read in 36 images, crop them and save them to a new file (one at a time). I figured out that I had to set the images to null after each iteration to allow Java to do its garbage collection. I.e:

```
BufferedImage img;
for (int i=0; i<36; i++) {
    img = ImageIo.ImageIO.read(anImageFile);
    /* Do what's needed with the image (cropping, resizing etc.) */
    ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputFile);
    img.flush();
    img = null;
}
```

I know it's now an old post but I hope that it can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Why dont u try calling `flush(`) on `BufferedImage` . It releases some of the resources held.

Comment: Isn't setUseCache used to enable/disable disk cache? How would this prevent OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: @apurv Sorry i was thinking the API is caching. Modifed the answer can u try that.